# Conditional mutate to assign a new colour with dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
value <- c(0,0.1,0.2,0.4,0,0.05,0.05,0.5)
time <- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)

test <- data.frame(value, time, ID)

 value time ID
1  0.00    0  1
2  0.10    0  2
3  0.20    0  3
4  0.40    0  4
5  0.00    1  1
6  0.05    1  2
7  0.05    1  3
8  0.50    1  4
```

I would like when the value at the time-point '0' is bigger than 0.1 to assign the color "red"
to all the ID values and when the values is smaller than 0.1 to assign the color "blue"
I would like my data.frame to look like this

```
 value time ID  color
1  0.00    0  1 blue
2  0.10    0  2 blue 
3  0.20    0  3 red
4  0.40    0  4 red
5  0.00    1  1 blue
6  0.05    1  2 blue
7  0.05    1  3 red
8  0.50    1  4 red
```

This is what I have tried so far but I do not get the color to all time points

```
test %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(color = case_when(value > 0.1 & time ==0 ~ "red", 
                           value < 0.1 & time ==0 ~ "blue"))
```

Any hint is highly appreciated

UPDATE::EDIT

---

One way that I see around is to add

```
test %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(color = case_when(value > 0.1 & time ==0 ~ "red", 
                           value < 0.1 & time ==0 ~ "blue"))%>% 
 tidyr:fill(color, .diretction ="updown")
```

any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(color = case_when(value > 0.1 & time ==0 ~ "red", 
                           value < 0.1 & time ==0 ~ "blue"))%>% 
 tidyr:fill(color, .diretction ="updown")```
````

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried if_else() ?

```
test %>% 
  mutate(color = if_else(value > 0.1 & time ==0,"red","blue"))
```

Or, nested if_else()'s for a step further:

```
test %>% mutate(color = if_else(value > 0.1 & time ==0,
                               "red",
                               if_else(time == 0,
                                       "blue",
                                       "0")
                               )
               )
```

If the rule is generic for the whole ID group you could use max() (or min()) of the group?

```
test %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(color = if_else(max(value) > 0.1 & time ==0,
                               "red",
                               if_else(time == 0,
                                       "blue",
                                       "not 0")
                               )
               )
```

Changing the data for ID == 1 to have one value above 0.1 and one value below it makes this more evident:

```
library(dplyr)

value <- c(2,0.1,0.2,0.4,0,0.05,0.05,0.5)
time <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1)
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)

test <- data.frame(value, time, ID)

test %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(color = if_else(min(value) > 0.1 & time ==0,
                         "red",
                         if_else(time == 0,
                                 "blue",
                                 "not 0")
  )
  )

  value  time    ID color
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1  2        0     1 blue 
2  0.1      0     2 blue 
3  0.2      0     3 blue 
4  0.4      0     4 red  
5  0        0     1 blue 
6  0.05     1     2 not 0
7  0.05     1     3 not 0
8  0.5      1     4 not 0
```

Comment: Dear Palandic, Thank you for your time but I think this does not work for me. I would like the colour of ID to be transfered to next time point

Comment: Hi LDT,  do mean that the ID's colour should be consistent? Because that's why I added the max() or min(), depending on the direction.

Comment: Yes yes exactly

Comment: Does using the min() or max() on the grouped condition not work?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I need to check again though, could you also check so as to be unfair

Comment: *not to be (sorry for my typo)